# Where can I see console.log messages logged in my Google Action fulfillment function or how can I simply log debug logging text?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, stackdriver, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm developing an action which uses fulfillment. I'm using the Inline Editor. I'm moving hard coded values into FireStore so data is stored inside the function itself. The FireStore request don't go as intended: although the fulfillment call doesn't fail it doesn't find the information it supposed to. I'm trying the good old `console.log` type logging to try to figure out what goes wrong. But those log messages don't show anywhere.

I looked at the Function's Firebase log, but it only contains basic events: execution started, finished, and a warning.

[image]

I also upgraded the action by attaching it to a payment planned project, and enabled Stackdriver logging. That also did not display my custom logging, only boilerplate messages.

[image]

Then I tried to add custom Stackdriver logging into the Inline fulfillment function following this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs
But I get an error because the `@google-cloud/logging` is not accessible in the nodejs environment of that inline function. So I'm kinda stuck. I cannot believe there's no easy way to simply log, but multiple Google searches didn't yield anything usable I could act on.

Comment: If you want a new package in that environment you can add it in the package.json tag. If you want to send logs to Firestore, you can [use a custom filter and Pubsub to a cloud function](https://medium.com/google-developers/how-to-connect-stackdriver-to-your-smart-home-server-for-error-logging-8a7a477241c2). My article is specific to smart home, but you can adapt it.

Comment: Was the issue resolved finally?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `console.log()` from the Inline Editor in Dialogflow *should* have the contents appear in the Cloud Functions for Firebase logging.

To test, I used the default code, and added a call to `console.log()` in the two Intent Handlers defined.

```
/ See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    console.log('welcome');
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    console.log('fallback');
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

I made sure the Inline Editor was enabled, the deployment happened, and then clicked on the link at the bottom of the page:

[image: Dialogflow Fulfillment Console]

When I test it, the Firebase Console shows it in the logging section, as expected.

[image: Firebase Cloud Functions logging]

This same logging is also in the Cloud Console. Note that you have to switch the *Resources* field from `Global` to `Cloud Function`.

[image: Google Cloud Console logging]

As for why you might not be seeing it, I'm honestly not sure. Some things to double-check which are easy to overlook:

- Confirm the logging is actually in the functions that should be called.
- Make sure you have clicked the "Deploy" button at the bottom of the Inline Editor after you have added the logging.
- Confirm that "Enable webhook call for this Intent" is turned on for **all** the Intents you want to handle with fulfillment.
  [image]
- Make sure you're looking at the same project.

Comment: I'm 100% sure the function is called which also has the logging statements. I certainly deployed (since for example when I tried to add the `@google-cloud/logging` it didn't compile. The fulfillment is not turned on for all intents because it is only needed at a certain step of the dialog flow. One thing though: I started off this action by exporting an existing action, creating a new action and importing the export into that. This is because the DialogFlow editor does not have a duplicate function. At the end of this duplication the new action's fulfillment was empty/default

Comment: I'm also 100% sure that the source action does not log anything, so while I'm testing I'm testing the one I'm thinking of and looking at. As I'm testing I see the other calls appearing, but not the console logs. The execution goes through areas where the console logs are. (My whole purpose is to extract data out of the JS code and place it into FireStore, but that's another story).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for the logs but are NOT using the inline editor, you can find them in your firebase console: https://console.firebase.google.com/

Comment: Inline editor or not this is the first place anyone looks at

Comment: Silly me then =)  I'm new to the Google dev environment and was looking in the Google Cloud logs instead of Firebase.

Comment: No problem, actually it's not bad to check back to the basics, I'll check again. On my screenshots I was checking the Functions output logs.