# How can I see a stack trace in cloud functions with DialogFlow fulfillment?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, stack-trace, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm struggling with debugging using fulfillment in DialogFlow.

I can see logs like the following:
[image]

However, I'm used to trying to determine the error based on a stacktrace. This particular error is occuring when I'm trying to send email via nodemailer/sendgrid. I am hoping that I can see more information to debug my issue, but I don't see anything. Within the first "Unhandled rejection" there is information that references a trace:

e.g.,
trace: "projects/arthurprojec-dhed12/traces/ca34795e6f34aweeba64307874ba7"

but when I look at traces via [this page](https://console.cloud.google.com/traces/list) and use the id of the trace "ca34795e6f34aweeba64307874ba7" to search I only see the same payload information from the logs.  I would like to see a trace that references my code (index.js) with more information. How can I do that?

Comment: I think your issue is related to the [link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764494/detailed-stack-trace-error-cannot-find-module-users-myhuser-downloads-myfolde) , you may need to modify your index.js code as per the instruction provided. Also I cannot access the link you provided in your question. please but the screenshot and the reference document you are following for this deployments.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm not sure the link you provided is applicable. Within DialogFlow/fulfillment there is the index.js and the package.json and the packages are correct otherwise it wouldn't deploy. The link I provided may only be available if you have google cloud services (via DialogFlow or otherwise). It's just a link to google clouds trace system that doesn't seem to provide stack trace information for the index.js.

Comment: I did the research on  your issue and it require more information and to investigate your project and logs to understand the issue. Unfortunately  this is not the platform to share private information . It is therefore suggested that please open an issue in the issue tracker by following the [document-1](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list).

Comment: I would have a look to this [article](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline#detecting_an_exception_in_worker_code) which explain how to troubleshoot exceptions using the [monitoring interlace](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf#accessing_the_monitoring_interface). There is also a [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60574915/where-can-i-see-console-log-messages-logged-in-my-google-action-fulfillment-func#clues) that could help